# Why is my desk still sticky?

Tags: repair

I recently applied a varathane bar and table finish to a desk of mine. It said it would be ready to touch after eight hours and fully cured after seventy two hours. its been three days and its still sticky. How do I change that, or make it not sticky?

Comment: If you have other finishing questions, I'd suggest you jump over to [woodworking.se]. _Tons_ of finishing info already available there, and more on tap if you can't find an existing answer to your question.

Comment: @RudyT-  unless the desk is in a damp cold room the sealer should have set by now. If it hasn't DON'T apply any more coats it will not adhere any better. The tackiness means something is preventing the varathane from curing properly. More coats will only make it more difficult to remedy.

Comment: If you can post a photo of the desk and the varathane it might be helpful (at least to me). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you apply varathane you're basically spreading around a plastic (polymer) dissolved in a solvent. When the solvent evaporates, the plastic comes out of solution and solidifies.

If its still sticky, the solvent is not entirely evaporated yet. You may need to wait longer because your room is cold. Or, perhaps your wood was not clean and had lots of natural oil on it (some sort of exotic wood) and this oil is slowing down the evaporation process.

Best option is to keep waiting (unfortunately) but if it does not set in a week+ then you may need to strip everything, clean everything, and start over.

Comment: I do still have some left, so if it doesn't get hard in a few days I'm going to try and add another thin coat.

Answer (score 1):

Reasons for the Varathene not curing correctly may be due to:

-It wasn't mixed correctly or completely stirred.

-The climate of the room wasn't ideal. If the humidity is high or the temperature to cold it will affect how it dries.

-It may be an incompatibility between the Varathane and the existing protective coat.

-Some furniture looks like wood ,but is actually a plastic made to appear like wood.

-Most likely the wood surface of the desk wasn't prepared correctly. If there are contaminants (ie oil, grime, dust, etc.) left on the wood this will alter how the Varathane works.

If the surface is tacky only in some areas you can use a putty knife to remove it. Wipe those scraped areas with a cheese cloth dampened with paint thinner or mineral spirits. When dry there should be no tackiness. Sand with a 150-180 grit paper and then wipe with thinner.

Apply the stirred (not shaken) Varathane to the cleaned areas only. Once dried apply to surface as usual.